# When i restart my phone my alarmclock app not working

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager, android-broadcastreceiver

i was trying to create my own alarm clock in android. The aim is that my alarm clock should play different songs based on my playlist . This is a college project . User sets an alarm and then forgets and then even after multiple restarts the alarm should play . I downloaded a sample code from  and was working on this . However on a restart of phone my alarms are getting lost . I found  that i need to use  broadcast receiver but still its not working on my phone lava phone . Can you please suggest if this code is fine . Here is my code link:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ADVyH0grEQ4g80HkFU1n2Cb4wxnQC4TX/view?usp=sharing

my android manifest file is..

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.alarmmanager">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name="MyBroadcastReceiver" >
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

my layout file...

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Number of seconds"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/time"
        android:layout_below="@+id/time"
        android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:text="Start" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

my receiver code..

```
    package com.alarmmanager;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Calendar;

/**
 * Created by bhaskar on 24-04-2018.
 *
 */

public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    MediaPlayer mp;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        mp= MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.alrm   );
        mp.start();
        Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.i("Alarm","Alarm"+ Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    }
}
```

mainActivity file

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button b1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    b1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startAlert();
        }
    });
}
public void startAlert() {
    EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.time);
    int i = Integer.parseInt(text.getText().toString());
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            this.getApplicationContext(), 234324243, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()
            + (i * 1000), pendingIntent);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm set in " + i + " seconds", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

}

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This is just too much code to look into

Comment: Whenever device restart pending intent are lost. you have to add Broadcast listener for boot complete and whenever broadcast fires you have to reset alarm for it.

Comment: thanks for your comment but in broadcast receiver class i just called log and toast but it did't toast or logged me i am not able to find that is broadcast receiver is listening or not how to identify any help.

Answer (score 1):

see this [official doc](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html#boot) for maintaining alarm when phone gets restarted.
in **Start an Alarm When the Device Boots** section

After getting the actual code i am editing this answer :

1) create new Receiver instead of using old one receiver

```
public class SampleBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
            // Set the alarm here.
            Log.d("AlarmDone", "AlarmDone");
        }
    }
}
```

2) register it in manifest file :

```
<receiver
            android:name=".SampleBootReceiver"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

3) change your old receiver code in menifest :

```
<receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver" />
```

**Note** : add permission in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

now your alarm will ring.

Comment: thanks @Hitesh but i have already implemented that code  and launch our app in LYF Flame 6 device with os 5.0 and in lava A52 with os 5.1 but not worked i have also tried in android emulator os(mashmello)but  not working on restart.

Comment: here is my full code link:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ADVyH0grEQ4g80HkFU1n2Cb4wxnQC4TX/view?usp=sharing

Comment: hello @kbhaskar i have seen your code and changed it. i am editing your my answer see it.

Comment: no, can't find your code and not run on restart can you please share the code.@Hitesh

Comment: see code here : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1G3bPBt6c0-7oxgrP8NxWBgkb6n8HzGJP

Comment: this code is working on  emulator but not n my own personal mobile "Lyf flame 6". i am trying to debug by logs . will post my findings

Comment: may be background service is stopping in your phone. find auto start or dozz mode off in your phone

Answer (score 0):

For me it works  only when i enable auto start[image]